# Sum and product of analytic functions that is not analytic

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, analyticity

The function

$$f(x) = \frac{2 + \cos x}{3} (2π - x) + \sin x$$

is the sum/product of analytic functions ($\cos(x)$,$\sin(x)$, linear), but all it's derivatives at $2\pi$ are $0$  ($f^n(2\pi)=0$).

I simply don't understand why.

Thanks,

Answer (score 12):

Says who? 
$$f^{(5)}(2\pi ) = -2/3.$$

Comment: +1 for taking the time to calculate $f^{(5)}$, but why would it be a problem if what the OP claims is true?

Comment: @AhmedHussein The function would have to be zero in a neighborhood of $2\pi$, and hence on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh gosh, I was afraid of doing it manually so I used a software and asked for $f^n(2\pi)=0$ .. Thanks a lot!! (I was going insane hehe)

Comment: @user7530: All of $\mathbb{C}$, in fact, since the derivatives are also complex derivatives.

Answer (score 6):

Set $x-2\pi=t$, so $x=t+2\pi$ and $\cos x=\cos t$, $\sin x=\sin t$. Thus you can consider
$$
g(t)=-\frac{2}{3}t-\frac{1}{3}t\cos t+\sin t
$$
and the Taylor coefficients at $0$ of $g$ are the same as the Taylor coefficients at $2\pi$ of $f$. We have
\begin{align}
g(t)&=-\frac{2}{3}t-\frac{1}{3}t\left(1-\frac{1}{2}t^2+\frac{1}{24}t^4+o(t^4)\right)+t-\frac{1}{6}t^3+\frac{1}{120}t^5+o(t^5)
\\[6px]
&=-\frac{2}{3}t-\frac{1}{3}t+\frac{1}{6}t^3-\frac{1}{72}t^5
+t-\frac{1}{6}t^3+\frac{1}{120}t^5+o(t^5)
\\[6px]
&=-\frac{1}{180}t^5+o(t^5)
\end{align}
contradicting your statement.

However, even if all derivatives are zero, there would be no problem: the function would be the constant zero function (in the whole circle of convergence of the Taylor series at $2\pi$).

Since the functions involved are entire, the circle of convergence is the whole line (if you think real) or the whole plane (if you think complex). Thus, in order to check that *some* derivative is nonzero at $2\pi$ you just have to check that $f(x)\ne0$ for some $x$. And
$$
f(0)=\frac{2+\cos0}{3}(2\pi-0)+\sin 0=2\pi\ne0
$$

Comment: Very nice approach!! It shows easily why only the fifth derivative is non-zero and can be done by hand without much effort. I appreciate your help!